# What's the simplest way to join two JPEG videos?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, merge, join

There are lot of options for ffmpeg and other software, I tried "concat" method with ffmpeg and tried mkvmerge, they didn't work well for JPEG video (MJPG).
I would use any tool that will keep quality, but preferably ffmpeg.

Here are specifications of the videos (they're both the  same):

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537331972
    compatible_brands: qt  pana
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 29166 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 28486 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-02T14:53:42.000000Z
      encoder         : Photo - JPEG
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s (default)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Simplest methods

The simplest method to join MJPEG videos would be to just use the `cat` tool or the [concat protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#concat) in `ffmpeg`. But I almost never suggest these as they only work for the simplest formats and there are too many ways for these methods to create broken outputs.

## Best method

The [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) is "smarter" than `cat` or the concat protocol so it is more robust and less likely to create broken outputs.

1. Create a text file named `input.txt` listing the videos you want to concatenate.

   ```
   file 'input1.mov'
   file 'input2.mov'
   ```
2. Run `ffmpeg` and give it `input.txt` as the input:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mov
   ```

   - This assumes your inputs have the same attributes: video format, frame rate, pixel format (YUV 4:2:0 vs YUV 4:2:2 vs YUV 4:4:4), width, height, audio format, channel layout, and sample rate.
   - The example uses [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode (`-c copy`) so it will avoid re-encoding and therefore preserve the quality.
   - See [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
ffmpeg -i {file1} -qscale:v 1 {file1}
ffmpeg -i {file2} -qscale:v 1 {file2}
ffmpeg -i concat:"{file1}|{file2}" -c copy {both}
ffmpeg -i {both} -qscale:v 2 {final}
```

And yes this works.

> they didn't work well for JPEG video (MJPG)

Why not? These commands are pretty generic and work for me. I hardly use mjpg and I did not find issues with Motion JPEG for ffmeg.

Alternatives

```
mencoder -ovc copy -oac copy {file1} {file2} -o {result}
```

Comment: I'm getting only black background on videos.